# Strange behavior with cell construction with Simple TableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have spent an insane time to fix this bug in our application. We are currently working in a chat and we have used a tableview for it.

Our tableview works fine until there is a certain amount of messages, after that, the table starts to flick. I coded without storyboards and for this reason I thought that constraints were the cause of trouble. So I decide to make a really simple tableview with some features of our chat tableview (actually our tableview is coredata linked and with a lot of graphic stuffs).

Because I suspected about constraints, I didn't use it in the code bellow just to see everything works fine, but it wasn't the case. In the gif image we can see two undesirable behaviors, the first one is that sometimes the table is re-generated completely, so cells disappear and appear in a very short time (this cause a very annoying flick). The second is no less annoying: cells are duplicated (I think this is for the cell reusability feature) but after a short period of time they are accommodated and everything goes fine.

https://github.com/hugounavez/pizzaWatch/blob/master/videoBug.gif
[image]

I tried adding the prepareForReuse() method and delete the views and creates them in the cell again but no results.

This is the example code, you can copy and run it with no problems in a **Playground**:

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


class Modelito{
    // This is the class tableview model
    var celda: String
    var valor: String
    init(celda: String, valor: String){
        self.celda = celda
        self.valor = valor
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    let tableview: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView()
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return table
    }()

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Click me to add new cell", for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Click me to add new cell", for: .highlighted)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()


    var model: [Modelito] = []

    let tipoDeCelda = ["MyCustomCell", "MyCustomCell2"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setupViews()

        self.tableview.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell")
        self.tableview.register(MyCustomCell2.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCustomCell2")

        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self

        self.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addRow), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Here I generate semi random info
        self.dataGeneration()
    }

    func setupViews(){

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableview)
        self.tableview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
        self.tableview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        self.tableview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        self.tableview.backgroundColor = .gray

        self.view.addSubview(self.button)
        self.button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.button.backgroundColor = .orange

    }

    func dataGeneration(){
        let number = 200
        // Based in the cell types availables and the senteces, we create random cell info
        for _ in 0...number{

            self.model.append(
                Modelito(celda: tipoDeCelda[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.tipoDeCelda.count)))], valor: "\(self.model.count)")
            )
        }

        self.tableview.reloadData()
        // After we insert elements in the model we scroll table
        let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath(row: self.model.count - 1, section: 0)]
        self.tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexPaths[0], at: .bottom, animated: false)
    }

    @objc func addRow(){
        // This function insert a new random element
        self.tableview.beginUpdates()
        self.model.append(
            Modelito(celda: tipoDeCelda[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.tipoDeCelda.count)))], valor: "\(self.model.count)")
        )

        // After inserting the element in the model, we insert it in the tableview
        let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath(row: self.model.count - 1, section: 0)]
        self.tableview.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
        self.tableview.endUpdates()
        // Finally we scroll to last row
        self.tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexPaths[0], at: .bottom, animated: false)

    }

}


extension ViewController{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.model.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 150
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let celldata = self.model[indexPath.row]

        switch celldata.celda {
        case "MyCustomCell":
            let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
            cell.myLabel.text = self.model[indexPath.row].valor
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomCell2", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell2
            cell.myLabel.text = self.model[indexPath.row].valor
            return cell
        }

    }
}


class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    var myLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 25, y: 0, width: 370, height: 30)
    }
}

class MyCustomCell2: UITableViewCell {

    var myLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        self.contentView.addSubview(myLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        myLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 370, height: 30)
    }

}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I changed the code base in the @Scriptable answer in order to be compatible with playground. At this point, I am starting to think that duplication cell bug is actually normal for tableview. In order to see the problem, the button should be pressed several times fastly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is reloading the tableview but it's removing that "annoying flick" and it's too smooth.

To fix that annoying flick just change addRow() function to

```
   @objc func addRow(){

    self.model.append(
        Modelito(celda: tipoDeCelda[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.tipoDeCelda.count)))], valor: "\(self.model.count)")
    )
    self.tableview.reloadData()
    self.scrollToBottom()
}
```

scrollToBottom() function:

```
func scrollToBottom(){
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.model.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Just try it.

Answer (score 1):

Using your current code in a playground produced a fatal error for me.

> 2017-11-13 15:10:46.739 MyPlayground[4005:234029] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (200) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

I changed the `dataGeneration` function to the following code which just calls `reloadData` once the data has been generated and scrolls to the bottom.

I think the error was that without reloading, there wasn't that many rows to scroll to.

```
func dataGeneration(){
        let number = 200
        // Based in the cell types available and the sentences, we create random cell info
        for _ in 0...number{

            self.model.append(
                Modelito(celda: tipoDeCelda[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.tipoDeCelda.count)))], valor: "\(self.model.count)")
            )
        }

        self.tableview.reloadData()
        // After we insert elements in the model we scroll table
        let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = [IndexPath(row: self.model.count - 1, section: 0)]
        self.tableview.scrollToRow(at: indexPaths[0], at: .bottom, animated: false)
    }
```

Once I got around the crash, the tableView worked fine for me. No flickering or duplication.

Comment: Thanks @scriptable, I changed the code above in the question, but I still present the same problem. Actually the problem appears when you click the button in a very short period of time (imaging that you are in a chat and the room participants are writing messages very fast)

Comment: I was typing the button very quickly, added about 30 rows in a minute and had no issues. have you tried running on a physical device? simulator can run alot slower than actual devices